# Dynamically creating/recalling/linking nameless objects

Tags: ruby, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

New to Ruby-land via The Odin Project. I'm writing an algorithm to generate binary search trees from a sorted array of random numbers.

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :value, :child_left, :child_right, :parent

  def initialize  (value, child_left = nil, child_right = nil, parent = nil)
    @value = value
    @child_left = child_left
    @child_right = child_right
    @parent = parent
    #Checker to verify object and link creation
    #puts "value: #{value}, self: #{self}, parent: #{parent}, child_left: #{child_left}, child_right: #{child_right}"
  end
end

def build_tree(arry, parent = nil)
  if arry.length > 2
    child_left = build_tree(arry[0...arry.length/2], arry[arry.length/2]) 
    child_right = build_tree(arry[(arry.length/2)+1..-1], arry[arry.length/2])
    Node.new(arry[arry.length/2], child_left, child_right, parent)
    #Can't link parent object until parent is created, but can't create child object until parent can be linked
  elsif arry.length == 2
    child_left = build_tree(arry[0...1], arry[1])
    Node.new(arry[1], child_left, nil, parent)
  elsif arry.length == 1
    Node.new(arry[0], nil, nil, parent)
  end
end
```

This results in properly generated node objects linked to their child objects, but only with the same fixnum value as the parent objects' value and not the actual parent object. It seems like a chicken/egg scenario. Either I'm committing some Object/Class creation sin here, or I simply lack the vocabulary to successfully search for a solution to my problem. Please advise.

EDIT: Maybe just a hint on some term(s) to search to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Off-topic: It may be better to chose `child_left` and `child_right` instead of your choices as its more Rubyesque :)

Answer (score 0):

First at all, you have an issue in the constructor:

```
def initialize  (value, childL = nil, childR = nil, parent = nil)
  @value = :value
  @childL = :childL
  @childR = :childR
  @parent = :parent
end
```

`:something` in Ruby is a Symbol, the build-in object, which is quite similar to String, but not modifiable. So, whatever you pass to `Node.new`, your variables will be set to `:value`, `:childL` and so on.

You probably wanted to set your class variables like this:

```
def initialize  (value, childL = nil, childR = nil, parent = nil)
  @value = value
  @childL = childL
  @childR = childR
  @parent = parent
end
```

Learn more on String and Symbols in Ruby [here](http://rubyforadmins.com/strings-and-symbols#symbols).